# Help with Conjugate points

Tags: differential-geometry, general-relativity

I want to understand the proposition 3.7 from the note [here](https://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/kroencke/lehre/ss2016/seminar/talk_10.pdf):

> Proposition 3.7. Let $(M, g)$ be a globally hyperbolic spacetime, S a
>   Cauchy hypersurface with future-pointing unit normal vector field $n$,
>   $\Sigma \subset S $ a compact 2-dimensional submanifold with unit
>   normal vector field $\nu$ in $S$, $p \in \Sigma$, $c_p$ the null
>   geodesic through $p$ with initial condition $n_p + ν_p$ and $q = c_p(r)$ for some $r > 0$. If $c_p$ has a conjugate point between $p$
>   and $q$ then $q ∈ I^+(\Sigma)$.

Simply, a conjugate point is where two geodesics intersect. I don't understand the proof because the piecewise curve constructed by gluing $\gamma$ and $c_p$ together is not time-like, it is everywhere null but it is claimed it is in $I^{+}(\Sigma)$.

Comment: The argument is that it isn't geodesic, so by 3.6 the point $q$ has to be in $I^+(\Sigma)$.

Comment: How did you conclude then it is in $I^{+}(\Sigma)$? Why it is not a space-like curve?